# Prove that $A/B$ is regular when $A$ is regular and $B$ is regular or not regular.

Tags: automata

Prove that $A/B$ is regular when $A$ is regular and $B$ is regular or not regular.
$$A/B=\{w: wx\in A\ \text  {   for some  }\ x\in B\}$$

Please give me a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
A/B = \bigcup_{x \in B} A/x
$$
and now use the fact that $A$ is regular.

Comment: $A/B = \bigcup_{x \in B} A/x$ - ok, I agree with you, but I can't finish it. I see that we should ues automata for language $A$. Simply, many of states will be accepted (these states that has a path "at" word $x$ - last state is accepting)

Comment: Do you know Myhill-Nerode's theorem?

Comment: No, I don't know

Comment: @user220688 Then look at Wikipedia... This is the key to your exercise.

Comment: What about solution without this theorem ?

Comment: How does this work when B is infinite?

Comment: @itsnotalie Same answer: look at [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill–Nerode_theorem).